# Custom field not showing

Tags: custom-field, loop, child-theme

I am trying to get 3 images and their links which I have defined as custom fields. The custom field aren't displayed and when I `var_dump()` my `get_post_meta()` it returns `string(0)""`, what am i doing wrong?

```
<div class="latest">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="boxes"> <?php echo "<p>".the_meta()."</p>"; ?>
<a href="<?php $show = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'promotional_link', true); ?>">
<?php //var_dump($show); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'promotional_image', true); ?>" height="200" width="260">
</a>
</div><!--boxes-->
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Show you code and screen of defined custom fields, pls.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż [here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0781l4qw22) is my screen of custom field and i showed you the code of my custom field

Comment: If `get_post_meta` returns an empty string ( '' ) then it hasn't been filled in for that post yet, or is empty. Simple as that. Maybe double check the meta key you are using.

Comment: @EricHolmes double check how? like typo? I checked for typo it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're in The Loop, you shouldn't need to use `get_the_ID()`.  Does this:

```
<div class="latest">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="boxes"> <?php echo "<p>".the_meta()."</p>"; ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'promotional_link', true); ?>">
<?php //var_dump($show); ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'promotional_image', true); ?>" height="200" width="260">
</a>
</div><!--boxes-->
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

work any better?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. when i var_dump it, the out is still string(0)""
Edit : the page is a sidebar template, which i am using in my own custom homepage (static), could that be the reason?

Comment: Could be.  Do this: `var_dump( $post->ID );` and compare it to the ID of the sidebar template page. If they don't match up, that's your problem -- you're trying to `get_post_meta()` of the wrong page.

Comment: i tired and it gave me output of 
NULL string(17) "promotional image" bool(true) , whereas my home page which uses the custom template in which i called the sidebar has a id of 6 (that is what it shows in status bar when i hover on home page). however i used the_meta and it showed the text and id as well.

Comment: Sorry, `var_dump( $post->ID );` gave you an output of `NULL string(17) "promotional_image" bool(true)`? That sounds odd. I would expect it to give `int 5` or something along those lines.

Comment: Ok i did `var_dump ($post->ID)` but it gives me `null` what could be wrong? when the_meta shows the output

Comment: use get_the_ID(). You are in the loop, so do `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'promotional_image' , true );`